# location.href = location.href wont redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my javascript code, in some point, i need to refresh the window (user has uploaded new image but in page still can see it)

i am wondering why is

```
location.href = location.href
```

not refreshing the window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are wanting your to redirect your page, use:

`window.location = location.href;`

Or, if it is a simple case of refreshing the page:

`window.location.reload();`

Comment: The thing is that the line is a callback in a onCLose method function of the jquery-ui dialog feature; could it be e.preventDefault()'in it?

Comment: I am just trying to simulate the browser default behavior from the callback of the ui-feature

Comment: One argument with using `window.location = location.href;` over `window.location.reload();` is that, `window.location.reload();` in some browser will show an pop up telling the you the form is resubmitted, while `window.location = location.href;` will not do that

Answer (score 11):

To refresh the window try:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: +1: I was editing my response when suddenly I see you've put the same.

Answer (score 2):

if you really really need to refresh the page you should do

```
 location.reload(true)
```

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet i don't like a page that forces me to refresh the page. :)

Comment: well... but in most of pages it is refreshed in a form onSubmit (its actually standard behavior)... isn't it?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet one thing is if you submit a form and then the pages refreshes, one other thing is that you refresh a page through javascript: why are you doing that?Can't you refresh the page manually withouth calling the server?