# angular routing something weird happening

Tags: html, angularjs

I am still learning angularjs so maybe there's something stupid I am not understanding but I have a really strange behaviour when using routing.

In my application I use the following code to define my routes:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/pneumatici/:chunka', {}).
    when('/pneumatici/:chunka/:chunkb', {});

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

And in a controller I manage them this way:

```
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (current,previous) {
    if (!($location.path().indexOf('/pneumatici') === -1)) {
      $scope.chunka = $route.current.params.chunka; $scope.chunkb = $route.current.params.chunkb;

      /** do my stuff with chunka and chunkb **/

    } else {
      window.location.href = $location.path();
    }
  });
```

I have no ngView, no template, nothing.
It works like a charm.

Please note the line where I actually force a page load in case the url is not intended to be managed by the controller appCtrl. 
I was forced to do that because once I define my route to catch '$routeChangeSuccess' all links in the page when clicked are catched by angular and no page load occurs even if the link  doesn't have the format defined with 'when'.
I would have like to do it with 'otherwise' but I could not understand how to, if doable.

**Now the problem.** 
In the page of course I have links like just '/privacy.html', if I click them the page load is correctly triggered and I do see '/privacy.html' but unfortunately once there **if I click the back button** I can see the url of the browser changing to (let's say) /pneumatici/foo/bar but no page load is triggered.

Please note in the privacy.html page I have no angular routing defined, there's no .config no .when; there's an anagular app defined, with a controller, but no injection of '$routeProvider' anywhere, no definition of any route.

What is happening? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

**Update.**
I found a viable solution adding:

```
angular.element("a").prop("target", "_self");
```

Angular routing is ignored for all 'a' elements with 'target' set to "_self", didn't know that.

Still if I look at this strategy as a whole doesn't sound very elegant to me and I would love to improve it. What I don't like is since I am defining the route in .config I should be able to tell angular to skip any url which do not match the format/path I defined there.

But I don't know if that is doable or not, **does anyone know out there?**

Comment: normal url with no hash prefix should work fine, not sure why you are having to do anything. Are you putting hash prefix in href for `/privacy.html` ?

Comment: You mean forward slash "/"? Sure I am.

Comment: no , url hash starts with `#` and angular path starts with `#/` ...remove the forward slash in your regular url and likely will work fine so long as don't have `#` there as well. A quick test using no forward slash prefix for normal url worked fine for me with no js needed

Comment: I am using html5 url, so there's no #. Se the line $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Comment: try absolute url instead of relative

Comment: Can you post a Plunker?

Comment: Hi @JoshDavidMiller I think this illustrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/43tub/6/

Comment: @rdjs This is probably a different issue. In your case, it's working as it should. HTML5Mode asks the server for the page to serve; it's the server's job to indicate whether or not to serve `index.html` or another page. If `index.html`, it uses Angular routing. In this case, it uses angular routing and `/Outside` doesn't match anything so the default route is used.

Comment: +1 Adding `target="_self"` to the anchor tag is a nice technique, and perhaps the non-hackiest solution to issues like this that I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By turning on html5mode your app should be acting like it should intercept everything on the site by default (from '/'.)

From that perspective, it seems like $location.path() should work in your explicit override, but it isn't really correct (`$location.url()` would be) and the browser already has the correct URL, so maybe you can't force a reload with [location.href = location.href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414889/location-href-location-href-wont-redirect#9414917) in your specific browser.

Rather than going down that path, I would do the following to make it DRY:

If you add a base href:

```
<base href="/pneumatici/"></base>
```

and replace `/pneumatici/` with `/` in your `when` clause(s):

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/:chunka', {}).
    when('/:chunka/:chunkb', {});
```

then you should just need this:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (current,previous) {

    $scope.chunka = $route.current.params.chunka;
    $scope.chunkb = $route.current.params.chunkb;

  /** do my stuff with chunka and chunkb **/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should let Angular manage all your routes like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

$routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: '/partials/home.html'
    })
    .when('/about',
    {
        controller: 'AboutController',
        templateUrl: '/partials/about.html'
    })
    .when('/privacy',
    {
        controller: 'PrivacyController',
        templateUrl: '/partials/privacy.html'
    })
    .when('/404',
    {
        controller: 'NotFoundController',
        templateUrl: '/partials/404.html',
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/404'
    });
});
```

Notice the otherwise above. That tells angular to load the 404 page when a route is not recognized.