# AngularJS routing hijacking non base URLs when page reload is expected

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm building an AngularJS app that is not located in the root location `domain.tld/blog`. I have routing setup for everything on the `/blog` base. I included the base tag in the head of the page `<base href="/blog">`. `html5Mode` is set to `true`. Within the app everything works as expected. However, when I click a non-angular URL outside of the base location the page isn't loaded. It seems that this location is caught by the `otherwise` function in the router:

```
ROUTER.otherwise({
  redirectTo : '/blog'
});
```

So when I click any url, i.e. `domain.tld/somewhere-else` it redirects to domain.tld/blog. Obviously this is what you would expect: for every URL that is not found in the router, redirect it to the 'homepage'. In my app this is not the desired behavior. All urls that are not in the router should be treated as a normal url and fire a page reload to that url.

So what I need is something like this:

```
ROUTER.otherwise(
     window.location = theRequestedUrl;
);
```

This doesn't work obviously. But somehow I need to get inside the otherwise part of the router and tell it to redirect to page with a page reload.

The following question is related: [angular routing something weird happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704720/angular-routing-something-weird-happening)

The following jsFiddle demonstrates the problem (thanks @rdjs!) http://fiddle.jshell.net/43tub/6/show/light/ . Click on the `/outside` link should do a full page refresh...

Comment: which version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: @rdjs 1.1.5, but the behavior is the same in 1.0.7

Comment: Does this demonstrate the problem accurately? http://jsfiddle.net/43tub/6/

Comment: @rdjs yes it does! Thank you for making the fiddle. Do you agree that clicking on the `/outside` is not the desired/expected behavior according to the documentation (as shown in the answer of Chardermani)?

Comment: I am having the same problem, could I ask where exactly are you setting your <base> url?

Comment: @rdjs in the `<HEAD>` of the HTML. I don't know how to do this with jsfiddle. But the behavior I'm seeing is identical to your fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js#L88), it looks important that the base is "/blog/" rather than "/blog".
Once I changed that I was able to refer to links relatively:

```
  <a href="./Book/Moby">Moby</a> |
  <a href="./Book/Gatsby">Gatsby</a> |
  <a href=".">base root</a> |
  <a href="/Outside">Outside</a> |  // gets a nice 404
```

My [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fgHf6/3/), note that location.pathname is always setting "[path]/", this also works hardcoded /_display/ while editing, but jsfiddle switches between _display/ and workingdir/show/ when running edited and save fiddles.

Comment: Indeed the missing trailing slash was the problem! I did not catch this because the trailing slash caused alot of errors with confliction libraries making me assume it should not have a trailing slash. After sorting out all the errors with the respond.js library (I dropped the proxy for the static host and use an extra conditional CSS for IE8 and below...) I am using it works as expected!

Comment: Thanks @DivZero! I'm suspecting that I'll be forced to add IE8 compatibility in my app before our launch, so it is great to hear about it now rather than hitting this on my own later..

Answer (score 9):

As per Angular [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

> In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the
>   browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.
>
> - Links that contain target element
>     Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
> - Absolute links that go to a different domain
>     Example: `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
> - Links starting with `'/'` that lead to a different base path when base is defined
>     Example: `<a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

See if this helps you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I tried this already. Using a target element is nog an acceptable solution for me. And links starting with `'/'` does **not** work as expected/documented. This is exactly what I need, however it just simply does not work...

Comment: This solution worked for me by using `target="_self"`  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could also do something like this:

```
var redirect = function(skip, url) {
    console.log("Redirecting to ", url);
    window.location.href = url
};
$routeProvider
    .when('/inside-router', { templateUrl: 'something.html' })
    .when('/get-me-away.html', { redirectTo: redirect })
    .when('/static/:file', { redirectTo: redirect })
```

Here is a [JSFiddle with a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/paldepind/BFYED/).

Basically you're abusing that AngularJS will call a function given in the `redirectTo` property and then do nothing more if the function doesn't return a string.

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps:

```js
$routeProvider
.when('...', {})
.otherwise({
  redirectTo: function () {
    window.location = location.pathname;
}});
```

using:
1.3.10/angular.js
1.3.10/angular-route.js