# AngularJS - ignoring route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, url-routing

I'm trying to get Angular to ignore links if the route doesn't exist, and let http do the work.

I have a large Laravel app, and I'm trying to implement AngularJS for some front end stuff.

The problem I have, is I want to slowly add Angular code to each page but have the rest of the app to function as usual.  It's not a single page app as such, but a multipage app with angluar functionality.

This is my Angular Routing:

```
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/clients/:ClientID', {
            templateUrl: "resources/js/angular/partials/DisplayLogCtrl.html",
            controller: 'DisplayLogCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            //Go to normal Laravel route
        });;

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Normal links, like `<a href="/" class="reminder_reminder">Dashboard</a>` don't function correctly.  The URL in the address bar is changed, but nothing changes onscreen.

Does anyone know why this happens?  ..and whether I'm going to be able to do what I want to do?

Comment: Does `multi page app` mean you are loading multiple pages from server that run the same angular code? Or are trying to slowly convert multiple pages into single page angular app? There is a big difference

Comment: Sorry.  Should have been clearer.  I want a Laravel app that has a single page app per page.

Comment: But why would you do that in the first place? And if you do...why would you use angular routing? Seems to defeat the purpose of using angular in the first place. To me it really doesn't sound like this is well thought through

Comment: My comments about angular routing could be wrong if you have one SPA per Laravel controller route...with sub routes inside angular. But you will have issues using html5 mode which requires a `base` tag if you aren't using sub directories (virtual in htaccess or real) on server to allow links in angular to know they aren't angular routes. Much simpler without html5 mode

Comment: essentially ... one directory per angular app with no other laravel output pages in that directory would make html5mode work without issues, the `<base>` would be that directory. Otherwise you have problems and would need to do a bunch of mapping of external  routes to detect within angular routechange events

Comment: I don't really understand how to do this, so I'm just reverting back to using the hash.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses hash routing, so ng-route only really looks at the path, not the whole url. A hash route looks like this: `www.example.com/#/client/14`. If you're on that page and click a link to '/', your browser will think it's already on that page and do nothing. I'm guessing angular doesn't see the path change, which is why nothing is happening, but it's hard to know without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Ahh.  I use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); which takes the hash out.  Is that killing me?

Comment: I am not familiar with it actually, but a quick browse of the docs reveals a number of potential gotchas: 1. do you have a `<base>` tag in the head of your document? 2. do your links have the "target" attribute set? 3 does your link start with a / and lead to a different path than your "base"? (taken from docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location))

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, and followed the instructions to the letter.  I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe post some of the commented out code.  Also, what happens when you turn off html5 mode? That might be instructional just for debugging purposes, you can turn it back on later.

Comment: Does the answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058305/angularjs-routing-hijacking-non-base-urls-when-page-reload-is-expected?rq=1) help? Also, you have a syntax error in the code you posted, two semicolons in a row after otherwise

Comment: I've decided not to use it, and use the hash instead.

Comment: Sorry.  You were right with "target".  Setting the target fixed everything.  Thanks.